# How to save/persist and access data on client side in javaScript?

Tags: jquery

How to save/persist and access data on client side in javaScript:Jquery?

I am using jsTree component of Jquery:JavaScript.

In bind() of jstree, after selection of node I want to save "data"

Comment: @scaisEdge Wrong, the Web Storage API is designed for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

You can store data on the client machine like this:

```
var data = { name: 'Bob', age: 12 };
Window.localStorage.setItem('person', data);
```

Then on a different page in the same domain, you can then retrieve this data:

```
var data = Window.localStorage.getItem('person');
```

Please note though that some browser security settings disable the localStorage so it might not work in all situations.

Some more reading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

The other alternative is to use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

```
document.cookie = "name=Bob";
document.cookie = "age=12";
console.log(document.cookie); // displays: name=Bob;age=12
```

Answer (score 4):

As @Tom mentioned, the Localstorage works fine.

An alternative way of storing data on the client is: (IndexedDB)

this storage system use key/value mechanism for storing data on the client side.

"IndexedDB is a large-scale, NoSQL storage system. It lets you store just about anything in the user's browser. In addition to the usual search, get, and put actions, IndexedDB also supports transactions." [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb)

definition of IndexedDB on MDN:

IndexedDB is a low-level API for client-side storage of significant amounts of structured data, including files/blobs. This API uses indexes to enable high-performance searches of this data. While DOM Storage is useful for storing smaller amounts of data, it is less useful for storing larger amounts of structured data. IndexedDB provides a solution."